# How to reverse an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So this is my array, I have tried `rsort` and `array_reverse` but its sorting it numerically and that's not what I want. I just want it in the opposite order.

```
[15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16]
```

Comment: `array_reverse` doesn't sort.  https://eval.in/151907

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php - "array_reverse — Return an array with elements in reverse order"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `true` to your `array_reverse`:

```
array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
```

In other words, try something like this:

```
array_reverse( $yourArray, true);
```

This way your keys are preserved and you achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

array_reverse should work. I just did this test:

```
$array = array(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16);
$rArray = array_reverse($array);

print_r($array);
print_r($rArray);
```

and the results were:

```
//for $array
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 14 [2] => 13 [3] => 12 [4] => 11 [5] => 10 [6] => 9 [7] => 8 [8] => 7 [9] => 6 [10] => 5 [11] => 4 [12] => 3 [13] => 2 [14] => 1 [15] => 30 [16] => 29 [17] => 28 [18] => 27 [19] => 26 [20] => 25 [21] => 24 [22] => 23 [23] => 22 [24] => 21 [25] => 20 [26] => 19 [27] => 18 [28] => 17 [29] => 16 )

//for $rArray
Array ( [0] => 16 [1] => 17 [2] => 18 [3] => 19 [4] => 20 [5] => 21 [6] => 22 [7] => 23 [8] => 24 [9] => 25 [10] => 26 [11] => 27 [12] => 28 [13] => 29 [14] => 30 [15] => 1 [16] => 2 [17] => 3 [18] => 4 [19] => 5 [20] => 6 [21] => 7 [22] => 8 [23] => 9 [24] => 10 [25] => 11 [26] => 12 [27] => 13 [28] => 14 [29] => 15 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The do-it-yourself-and-more-fun solution:

```
$oldArray = array(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16);
$length = count($oldArray);
$start= $length - 1;
$newArray=array();
for ($x = $start; $x >=0; $x--)
{
  array_push($newArray,$oldArray[$x]);
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Prints:

```
Array ( [0] => 16 [1] => 17 [2] => 18 [3] => 19 [4] => 20 [5] => 21 [6] => 22 [7] => 23 [8] => 24 [9] => 25 [10] => 26 [11] => 27 [12] => 28 [13] => 29 [14] => 30 [15] => 1 [16] => 2 [17] => 3 [18] => 4 [19] => 5 [20] => 6 [21] => 7 [22] => 8 [23] => 9 [24] => 10 [25] => 11 [26] => 12 [27] => 13 [28] => 14 [29] => 15 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to reverse an array simply put it in a stack (or at least use that logic).

FILO (First in last out) thus you have swapped the order.

A Stack Overflow question around php stacks can be found here:
[PHP Stack Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210324/php-stack-implementation)

Are you familiar with other languages? I don't use php much.

Simply create a new object and add the end to it. Ex 
new Array a
a.push(oldArray.removelast())...